# MOSFET Body terminal

Tags: mosfet

What is the point of the body terminal in a MOSFET?

If we assume Vsource=0 and Vdrain>0 then we will have a linearly changing voltage from drain to source. Then if Vgate>0, depending on the difference between Vgate and the voltage on each point in the MOSFET below the gate, we might, or might not, have an inversion channel.

So what is the actual purpose of the body being connected to source? Why don't we simply let it float? I know that if the body voltage is different than the source voltage, the threshold voltage will change, but what if the body terminal is left to float?

Comment: fyi: MOSFETs with the bulk wired out to an actual fourth pin are very rare.